# Run formula after matching to corresponding value

Tags: indexing, google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I have a column 'AV' which I am trying to display a percentage of monthly information. I have this formula for the 'AV' so far:

```
=iferror((AU61/AN61),"0%")
```

'AN' is the column for values in June and I have another column 'AO' that has values for July. 'AC' is the column that displays what Month we would use to determine if we use 'AN' or 'AO'.

Is there a formula that would be able to look at 'AC' and if 'AC' says June then it will do: `=iferror((AU61/AN61),"0%")` and if it says July then it will do `=iferror((AU61/AO61),"0%")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
=if(AC61="June",iferror((AU61/AN61),"0%"),if(AC61="July",iferror((AU61/AO61),"0%"),"")
```